# Change all Web.*.config files in first stage in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault, episerver

I need to change the items inside appsettings on all the Web.*.config files in first stage step. That is I can't do transformation in every step in release pipeline. The reason is that I use Episerver DXC/DXP.

I have 4 stages; *"Upload Package", "Integration", "Preproduction"*, and *"Production"*.

The values is stored i Azure Key Vault.

Is there any smart way to do this?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this? Does below answers give you the help on your puzzle solved? Consider to [accept one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it would also help to others:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do was replace variables in config files from Azure Key Vault before transformation on config files because it can't be done (at this point) during the release pipeline when using Episerver DXC. What I did was replacing them during the build pipeline instead.

Made the variable substitution in Powershell during the build pipeline. Import the Key Vault secrets as separate task before the Powershell task, list all the one I would use as environment variables in the Powershell task.

The environment variables I named the same as the one it should replace in the config files (ex **SomeApiKey_Integration**). Go through the config files, look for two anything between two double underscores and replace them with value from the environment variable ((Get-ChildItem $variable).Value).

In the config files and environment variable they are named as previous stated, **SomeApiKey_Integration**. Key Vault name and environment variable value as SomeApiKey-Integration.

Comment: I also need to replace values in webconfig file and also used replaced token tasks for that, but still I have a little confusion, after tokenization implemented on actual main web.Config file which is also used by developers and also added token, if i add test = '#{token}#' than developers will not able to run the application because values changed with  #{}#
Is their any way that we can replace values without 'Replace token'

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [guide](https://world.episerver.com/digital-experience-cloud-service/development-considerations/environment-configurations/) on config transforms for DXC? https://world.episerver.com/digital-experience-cloud-service/development-considerations/environment-configurations/

Answer (score 0):

If `File transformation` is not suitable for your project, what about using **powershell** script to do the item change?

**Sample:**

Here is my example `web.product.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="service.tasks" type="HRNetTaskService.TaskConfigurationSection, TaskService" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Production" connectionString="xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RestServiceUrl" value="https://sample.net" />   
  </appSettings> 
</configuration>
```

Now I want to update the `connectionString` of `.config` file. Add `replace.ps1` into repos with below scripts, then call this `replace.ps1` file in Powershell task via passing corresponding dynamic value:

```
Param(
[string]$source,
[string]$connectionstring
)
$webConfig = $source
$doc = (Get-Content $webConfig) -as [Xml]
$root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
$activeConnection = $root.connectionStrings.SelectNodes("add");
$activeConnection.SetAttribute("connectionString", $connectionstring);
$doc.Save($webConfig)
```

[image]

---

Here `$(ProductValue)` is the variable that you configured in Azure key vault. Its call way is same with the pipeline variable. Just you need [link](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/) the Azure key vault into azure devops, then combine it with `Variable group`.